# Selecting records based on maximum value of another field

Tags: visual-foxpro

I am trying to pull a list of distinct city names with their latitudes and longitudes based on the maximum value of the land area field.   The best I get is a "SQL: Error correlating fields" error.

```
SELECT a.primary_city as city ;
    , a.state as state_id ;
    , SPACE(30) as state_name ;
    , a.approximate_latitude as latitude ;
    , a.approximate_longitude as longitude ;
FROM citystate a ;
WHERE a.area_land = ;
    (SELECT MAX(VAL(b.area_land)) ;
    FROM citystate b ;
    WHERE (b.primary_city = a.primary_city ;
        AND b.state = a.state)) ;
GROUP BY a.primary_city ;
    , a.state ;
    , a.approximate_latitude ;
    , a.approximate_longitude
```

Not sure this will even work so hoping for some help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Such SQL is not supported in VFP. You can write that as:

```
SELECT csa.primary_city as city ;
    , csa.state as state_id ;
    , SPACE(30) as state_name ;
    , csa.approximate_latitude as latitude ;
    , csa.approximate_longitude as longitude ;
FROM citystate csa ;
INNER JOIN ; 
    (SELECT primary_city, state, MAX(VAL(area_land)) as maxALand ;
    FROM citystate ;
    GROUP BY primary_city, state ) csb ;
  ON csb.primary_city = csa.primary_city ;
        AND csb.state = csa.state ;
WHERE VAL(csa.area_land) = csb.maxALand
```

Answer (score 0):

VFP has not problem at all with 'such SQL', contrary to the pronouncement of master Basoz on the matter.

Normally you should get a type mismatch error because of the comparison of `land_area` to `max(val(land_area))`. Fox is nowhere near as eager with implicit conversions as, for example, MS SQL Server, and hence you have to match data types correctly.

However, not knowing what your table structures are it is difficult to offer specific pointers as to where the problem may be. Here are two similar queries using sample data available in VFP (using the freight cost as a stand-in for `land_area` value):

```
_VFP.DoCmd("set path to " + set("PATH") + ";" + _SAMPLES)

use Northwind/orders alia nw_orders in sele("nw_orders") shar noup agai

sele o.shipcountry, o.shipcity, o.shipname, o.orderid, o.freight ;
   from nw_orders o ;
   wher o.freight == ( ;
      sele max(x.freight) from nw_orders x wher x.shipcountry == o.shipcountry ) ;
   orde by 1 ;
   into curs nw_result
brow last nowa

use Tastrade/orders alia tt_orders in sele("tt_orders") shar noup agai

sele o.ship_to_country, o.ship_to_city, o.ship_to_name, o.order_number, o.freight ;
   from tt_orders o ;
   wher o.freight == ( ;
      sele max(x.freight) from tt_orders x wher x.ship_to_country == o.ship_to_country ) ;
   orde by 1 ;
   into curs tt_result
brow last nowa
```

Tastrade and Northwind are very similar in structure and contain very similar data; one or the other should be available in your VFP installation. However, neither sample database seems to in the public domain, at least not in the VFP incarnation. That is why I put Northwind first, since it is publicly available in versions for MS SQL Server etc. pp., and dumping its orders table to Fox format should not present insurmountable difficulties.

Here's a C# LINQPad script for running the Northwind query via OLEDB:

```cs
const string DIR = @"d:\dev\sub\FoxIDA\data\Northwind\";
const string SQL = @"
sele o.shipcountry, o.shipcity, o.shipname, o.orderid, o.freight
   from orders o
   wher o.freight == (sele max(x.freight) from orders x wher x.shipcountry == o.shipcountry) 
   orde by 1";

using (var con = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("provider=VFPOLEDB;data source=" + DIR))
{
    using (var cmd = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(SQL, con))
    {
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteReader().Dump();         
    }
}
```

Obviously, you'd need to adapt the `DIR` definition to where the data is located on your machine. Equally obviously you'd have to use a 32-bit version of LINQPad, since there is no 64-bit OLEDB driver for VFP. Here's the result:

[image: LINQPad query result]